# Sencha push view on image tap

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Can we push a view on image tap event without using NavigationView (As I am using Container for that but not Navigationview) without destroying the previous view,so as when user go back ( Currently with android hard back button) ,they should be able to view the previous view again.

Comment: Using event delegation & Card layout.. yes you can..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you definetely can. What you are looking for is a `View` with a `card` layout. Checkout this guide on layouts http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/layouts

Just use an `Ext.Image` component and you should get a `tap` event without messing with event delegation: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Img-event-tap